# What is wrong with this code LOGICAL ERROR

Tags: c

I`m simply trying to compare two integers. The code runs fine however gives the wrong results.

```
int userenter;

int compareseatfirst(Flights *FDA[], String destination, String dep_date,     int FC_seats)
{
        int j=0; 
        for (int i=0;i<MAXARRAYSIZE;i++)
        {
            //test for null

            if (FDA[i]==NULL) 
            {
                i++;//skip over this flight record

         }
            else if(strcmp(FDA[i]->dep_date,dep_date)==0 && (strcmp(FDA[i]->destination,destination)==0) && (FDA[i]->FC_seats<userenter)) 
        {
           printf("NOT ENOUGH");
           getchar();
            j++;
            if(j >= 10)
            {
               break; // Stop Looping as Array is full
            }
        }
        else if(strcmp(FDA[i]->dep_date,dep_date)==0 && (strcmp(FDA[i]->destination,destination)==0) && (FDA[i]->FC_seats==userenter)) 
        {
            printf("JUST ENOUGH");
            j++;
            if(j >= 10)
            {
               break; // Stop Looping as Array is full
            }
        }
        else if(strcmp(FDA[i]->dep_date,dep_date)==0 && (strcmp(FDA[i]->destination,destination)==0) && (FDA[i]->FC_seats>userenter)) 
        {
            printf("ENOUGH");
            j++;
            if(j >= 10)
            {
               break; // Stop Looping as Array is full
            }
         }
    }   
   return j; // Return Count of the Flights found.
```

}

When ever it runs it all gives the "ENOUGH" answer despite the user enter being more than or equal to the the FC_seats.

Comment: int userenter ; give the colon. and try to post the full code.

Comment: that is the full code

Comment: You don't have main() function or structure declaration!!

Comment: When you skip an entry, don't increment `i`. Use `continue` instead; that will go straight to the update part of the `for` loop (i.e. `i++`) _and_ it will enforce that `i` doesn't go out of bounds, because the loop condition is checked. (Oh, now that I've cleaned up the indentation I see that you increment and have `else` clauses for everything else. That means that you are effectively incrementing twice when you encounter an empty record. You skip this record and the next one.)

Comment: M Oehm could you just re do my code and post it up because I do not fully understand what you are saying please

Comment: @Aaron Johnson.: What M Oehm said is--- if (FDA[i]==NULL) {
           continue  ;}   //i++;//skip over this flight record

Comment: Track the variable `i` in your loop and you will understand. The logic shouldn't be: Oh, I skip this record, so I increment `i`. That's wrong, because `i` will be incremented anyway. The logic should be: Oh, I skip this entry, so I'll just do nothing in this pass through the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Track the variable `i` in your loop and you will understand. The logic shouldn't be: Oh, I skip this record, so I increment `i`. That's wrong, because `i` will be incremented anyway. The logic should be: Oh, I skip this entry, so I'll just do nothing in this pass through the loop. –  M Oehm